# Property initialization in kotlin with and without a setter

Tags: kotlin

Coming from a Java background, I am trying to wrap my head around properties in Kotlin.

Consider the following code example:

```kotlin
class Rectangle (var width: Double, var height: Double) {
    var area: Double  // ERROR: must be initialized
        get() = width * height
}
```

According to what I have learned so far, if a backing field is created for a property, then the property must be initialized.

A backing field will be created in the above code example for the `area` property, so compiler complains that `area` must be initialized.

Initializing `area` in an initializer block can fix the compiler error:

```kotlin
class Rectangle (var width: Double, var height: Double) {
    var area: Double
        get() = width * height

    init {
        area = width * height
    }
}
```

We can also initialize `area` with its declaration:

```kotlin
var area: Double = width * height
```

#### Problem

However, if I add a setter to the `area` property in the above code example with the initializer block, compiler again complains that `area` must be initialized.

```kotlin
class Rectangle (var width: Double, var height: Double) {
    var area: Double  // ERROR: must be initialized
        get() = width * height
        set(value) { field = value }

    init {
        area = width * height
    }
}
```

#### Question

I have the following questions:

- Why does compiler complains if I add a setter?
- The `area` property is still initialized in the initializer block, so why the error (initializing `area` inside a secondary constructor also doesn't help)?
- What's the difference with and without a setter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Kotlin doesn't need to generate a backing field for your property you are not required (nor allowed) to use an initializer. A property declared like this (with `val`, not `var`) doesn't need a backing field and doesn't have an initializer:

```
val area: Double
    get() = width * height
```

After all, nothing needs to be stored, the property is essentially just a function that always calculates the value when required.

Now, when you change that to `var` you allow the property to also be *set*, even without an explicit `set` function. When a property can be set, Kotlin automatically creates a backing field for that property so a value can be stored. This backing field - although not directly visible - needs to be initialized via the property. That's why you experience the error in your first example.

The error from your second example occurs because you defined a custom setter that can access the backing `field` - even *before* the `init` block is executed. Accessing something that isn't initialized isn't allowed, hence the compile error. If you initialize the property as part of the property declaration (`var area: Double = 0.0`), you can define a custom setter without problems because the initialization is already done when the setter could be executed.

Comment: _"...you defined a custom setter that can access the backing field - even before the init block is executed"_ - As far as I understand, init blocks are executed during the initialization of an object, so how can a setter be invoked before it is initialized? Initializing `area` inside the init block will invoke the setter but that will just assign to the backing field, so isn't the requirement of initializing the property fulfilled?

Comment: A setter is just like a method in Java, so it can be invoked before the class is fully constructed.

Comment: When an object is created, the initialization is done from top to bottom. First, `var area: Double` is handled, then the `init` block. Say your custom setter would do something like `field = field * 2`, it would try to read `field`. That wouldn't be a problem if the setter could only be called when the entire object (including the init block) is handled. It isn't, though: The init block (or anything else during object initialization) could call `area = ...` before the init block does the initialization of `area`....

Comment: ... Then the setter would be executed before the initialization and you would access an unitialized property.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is generally correct. Now, speaking about all mentioned cases:

```kotlin
var area: Double
    get() = width * height

init {
    area = width * height
}
```

There is no setter, so in the initialization block we set the value of the field directly.

```kotlin
var area: Double
    get() = width * height
    set(value) { field = value }

init {
    area = width * height
}
```

This time we have a setter, so in the initialization block we actually do not set the field, but call the setter. From the perspective of the compiler, we didn't set the field in the constructor. We called a function which did this, so it is effectively set, just not in the constructor.

```kotlin
var area: Double = width * height
    get() = width * height
    set(value) { field = value }
```

This is again fine, because this syntax doesn't call the setter, but initializes the field directly.

Comment: _"There is no setter, so in the initialization block we set the value of the field directly."_ - Will it not call the auto-generated default setter implementation? _"...This time we have a setter, so in the initialization block we actually do not set the field, but call the setter"_ - Setter is called to set the backing field, so why compiler complains? This is what's confusing me.

Comment: @Yousaf Compiler doesn't think like humans do. It is obvious to us the setter sets the backing field. For the compiler this is setting a field vs calling a function. It doesn't follow to the function and analyze its body to understand what it does do. Of course, this specific case is relatively simple and compiler could do such analysis. It just doesn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your second block of code is a special case where it lets you defer initialization of the property’s backing field. Confusingly, it allows you to do this using the same syntax as if you were setting a `var` property. When the property actually is a `var` then the typical meaning of the syntax is used—you are setting the property. Which means now your code is lacking a backing field initialized, so the compiler complains.

Side note, neither do your examples makes practical sense because there’s no point in having a backing field if the getter doesn’t ever read it.

Comment: _"Your first block of code is a special case..."_ - Do you mean the second code block with the initializer block? The first code block throws an error. And if I understand your explanation correctly, 2nd code block is a special case which lets us defer the initialization but in general, a `var` property must be initialized, either in the declaration or in the constructor?!

Comment: Regarding your side note, I am just trying to make sense of property initialization in kotlin with silly examples.

Comment: Yes I meant second code block

Comment: All properties that use fields must be initialized. And if they have a custom setter, it must be done at the declaration site, as far as I know. In practice, in several years of using Kotlin, I have never had an occasion where I initialized a property anywhere besides its declaration site. Why complicate things by doing it elsewhere? Note, you can use a `run { }` block for initializing if it’s more complicated than a one liner or function chain.